# GridView won't display images

Tags: android, gridview

Is there any way to have my app load all of the pictures that are visible on the screen on its own and without me having to rotate the device or swipe? I've noticed it works with some sizes and not with others (but I need the larger size that it is at now). Also, App doesn't work if I don't have the two sets of placeholder images (no clue why). Thanks in advance!

Here is my Image Adapter:

```
package tk.talcharnes.popularmovies;

 import android.content.Context; import android.view.View; import
 android.view.ViewGroup; import android.widget.BaseAdapter; import
 android.widget.GridView; import android.widget.ImageView;

 import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

 /**  * Created by Tal on 2/24/2016.  */ public class ImageAdapter
 extends BaseAdapter {   //  private static String[] desc = new
 String[9];
     private static String[] desc = {
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
"http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg",
             "http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/jQuery-Ajax-Loading-Overlay-with-Loading-Text-Spinner-Plugin.jpg"
     };
     private static String[] imageArray = getDesc();
     private Context mContext;
     //private String[] asc = new String[PostersFragment.getMovieModelListLength()];
     private static String[] asc = {};

     public ImageAdapter(){

     }


     public int getCount() {
        try{
             return imageArray.length;}
         catch(NullPointerException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
             return 0;
         }
     }

     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
         mContext = c;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

public Object getItem(int position) {
         return imageArray[position];
     }

     // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ImageView imageView;
         if (convertView == null) {
             // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
             imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
             int pixels = (int) (mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185*pixels, 277*pixels));

             convertView = imageView;
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             //  imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
         } else {
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
         }
         Picasso.with(mContext).load(imageArray[position])
                 .placeholder(R.drawable.sample_0)
          //       .resize(185,277)
                 .into(imageView);
         //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageArray[position]));
         return imageView;
     }



     public static String[] getAsc() {
         return asc;
     }

     public static void setAsc(String[] asc) {
         ImageAdapter.asc = asc;
     }

     public static String[] getDesc() {
         return desc;
     }
     public static void setImageArray(String[] arrayName){
         imageArray = arrayName;
     } }
```

And here is my fragment:

```
    package tk.talcharnes.popularmovies;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class PostersFragment extends Fragment {
    private static List<MovieModel> movieModelList;
    private static int movieModelListLength;
    GridView gridView;
    private String done = null;
    ImageAdapter adapter;
    public PostersFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        FetchPostersTask fetchPostersTask = (FetchPostersTask) new FetchPostersTask().execute();
        // should find gridview on the view which you are creating
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext()));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "You clicked " + movieModelList.get(position).getTitle() ,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    private final String BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/";
    private String middle_section = "discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=";
    private String jSonUrl = BASE_URL + middle_section + BuildConfig.MOVIE_DB_API_KEY;
    //Get movie posters and data
    public class FetchPostersTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchPostersTask.class.getSimpleName();
        //will contain raw Json data
        String posterJsonString = null;

        public Void parseMovieJson()
                throws JSONException{
            JSONObject jsonParentObject = new JSONObject(posterJsonString);
            JSONArray movieJSonArray = jsonParentObject.getJSONArray("results");

            movieModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < movieJSonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject movieJsonObject = movieJSonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                MovieModel movieModel = new MovieModel();
                movieModel.setTitle(movieJsonObject.getString("title"));
                movieModel.setOverview(movieJsonObject.getString("overview"));
                movieModel.setPoster_path(movieJsonObject.getString("poster_path"));
                movieModel.setRelease_date(movieJsonObject.getString("release_date"));
                movieModel.setVote_average(movieJsonObject.getString("vote_average"));
                movieModelListLength++;

                movieModelList.add(movieModel);
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void ...params) {

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
//
            //will contain raw Json data
            // String posterJsonString = null;
            try{

                //open connection to api

                URL url = new URL(jSonUrl);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                //read input into string
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if(inputStream == null){
                    //nothing else to do in this case
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if(buffer.length()==0){
                    //nothing here, don't parse
                    return null;
                }

                posterJsonString = buffer.toString();
            }
            catch(MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error", e);
                return null;
            }
            finally {
                if(urlConnection != null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if(reader != null){
                    try{
                        reader.close();

                    }
                    catch (final IOException e){
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try{
                parseMovieJson();;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            //ImageAdapter.setAsc(movieModelList.);
            String[] asc = new String[movieModelList.size()];
            for(int i = 0; i < asc.length; i++){
                asc[i]=(getMovieModelList().get(i).getPoster_path());
                //ImageAdapter.setAsc(asc);
            }
            adapter.setImageArray(asc);
        }
    }
    public static List<MovieModel> getMovieModelList(){
        return movieModelList;
    }
    public static int getMovieModelListLength(){
        return movieModelListLength;
    }

}
```

I believe this last piece should be last bit of needed code if at all which is the layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PostersFragment">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"

        />

</FrameLayout>
```

Sorry in advance if code is a little clunky I am new programmer and have commented out a few things just to make sure I have them available if needed later. Thanks in advance again :D

Update: When I try to put in code: adapter.notifyDataSetChange(); after adapter.setImageArray(asc); I get this error code:

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: tk.talcharnes.popularmovies, PID: 6558
                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void tk.talcharnes.popularmovies.ImageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at tk.talcharnes.popularmovies.PostersFragment$FetchPostersTask.onPostExecute(PostersFragment.java:171)
                                                                               at tk.talcharnes.popularmovies.PostersFragment$FetchPostersTask.onPostExecute(PostersFragment.java:70)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                                               at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5290)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

I did get a similar error code previously which was a null pointer error for an array I had which somehow got fixed when I set the array to the array I have named desc, and then I had the postersfragment change immagearray to be asc array once it was done with asynctask. No idea why that stopped the error and pretty much fixed it though.

Answer (score 1):

Call [`notifyDataSetChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your adapter when you add items like this

```
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

(you can do this at the end of `onPostExecute()` method)

Comment: App crashes when I do that :/ Also why would it update on certain image sizes and not others? So weird!

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I just added the error and brief description under the update section of the post. :D

Comment: looks like it ended up being that a bad git revert messed up my adapter and this was the correct answer! I just had to initialize adapter variable to equal (new ImageAdapter(getContext()))            Thanks!